# запуск Simple Draw под Mac Os

Tags: python, macos, simple-draw

Все установленно. python 3.8 pygame 1.9.6 simple-draw 2.6.6/ При запуске кода Пайчарм обращается к питону (при этом ошибку не выдаетт в коде) . запускается Python Launcher, и на этом все. в стадии загрузки постоянной. а должно же запускаться окно с графикой

Answer (score 0):

Установите пакет pygame версии 2.0.0.dev6:

pip3 install pygame==2.0.0.dev6

А затем повторно установите simple_draw, не обращая внимание на предупреждение о несовместимости версий pygame и simple_draw.